# How to find svg element with selenium and click on this icon?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, svg

I'm building a python testing bot, and I'm trying to click on the svg icon, but I'm not sure how to select it.

I tried selecting by Xpath, but I can't seem to be able to navigate it to the icon. Here's my HTML code for the selected icon:

```
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-vubbuv" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="tuneIcon">
```

and this I was trying to run unsuccessfully

```
find = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[name()="svg" and @class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-vubbuv" and @focusable="false" and @aria-hidden="true" and @viewBox="0 0 24 24" and @data-testid="tuneIcon"]')
find.click()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It'll be helpful to provide a little more information about what you've tried and _how it failed_.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it can be tricky to interact with the SVG from selenium.

The normal click won't likely work.

I suggest you to try the following options:

1. Check the Xpath. The provided Xpath is quite cumbersome, some of the used attributes may change once you move the mouse over the element. Try to shorten it to smth like '//*[name()='svg' and @data-testid='tuneIcon']'
2. Try ActionChains

```
    svg=broswer.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg' and @data-testid='tuneIcon']"))
    actions = ActionChains(browser)
    actions.click().perform()
```

3. Try clicking with JS

```
    svg=broswer.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg' and @data-testid='tuneIcon']"))
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", svg)
```

4. Try to dispatch the click event forcefully to the target svg

```
    svg=broswer.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg' and @data-testid='tuneIcon']"))
    broswer.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));", svg)
```

5. Try to locate the parent element (e.g. some div above the svg), and click on it. It's called 'event capturing' when clicking on the parent element triggers an action on the child element. Sometimes it may work.