# Selenium. How to click on the Next svg icon (no buttons tag) to go to the next page

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on Next ('Siguiente') to go to the next page but I'm noob enough to have spend one day trying what I have found in stackoverflow and different forums with no luck.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.common import MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException

url='https://www.online.bmsupermercados.es/es/c/ofertas/99999?orderById=5&page=1'

# Set ChromeOptions() and open window
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--nogpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chrome/chrome"
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled") 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) 
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

#Close cookies and Postal Code panels
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 200)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Rechazar todo']"))).click()
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='use' and @*='#icon-cancel']")))
for i in element:
    i.click()

#Scroll down (this last part is required for another action that mouse hover while paging down)
body = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html')
body.click()
body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

And here is where I'm not able to click the *Next* icon to go to the next page. The following are some of the tries I've done, in some of them it says it's not a button and in others I just receive the TimeoutException:

```
next_page_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@routerlink='./']//*[name()='svg']/*[local-name()='title' and text()='Siguiente']")))
next_page_link.click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@routerlink='./']//*[name()='svg']/*[local-name()='title' and text()='Siguiente']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a//*[contains(text(), 'Siguiente')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.next-page.d-flex.u-cursor--pointer a[rel=next]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a//*[name()='svg']//*[local-name()='Siguiente']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "//svg[contains(text(),'Siguiente')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Siguiente'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Siguiente')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//title[@text='Siguiente']"))).click()

# Obtain button by link text and click. 
button = body.find_element("link text", "Siguiente")
button.click()

#This is the only one that didn't get the TimeOutException:
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a//*[name()='svg']//*[local-name()='use']"))).click()
```

The error in the last one is:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <use xlink:href="#icon-double-caret"></use> is not clickable at point (935, 492). Other element would receive the click: <div id="paginator-input" class="paginator-input">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.105)
```

How can it work?
Thank you very much in advance to those of you who take the time to read and say something.

Comment: right-click on the Next button and choose "Inspect".  Copy/paste that markup into your post.  (locator's probably something like //button[text()='Siguiente'] ... but just a guess)

Comment: That's what I've done in all the tries I shown after searching for hours in different answers. I've read that when it's a svg it's a bit trickier, but haven't found the solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to click on svg element in your case.

If you really want to do this, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77862519/23182657) answer.

But you can achieve your goal much more easily. You can either get the number of pages, and just fill in the paginator input, or click on the <a> element which is an ancestor to your svg (and which is doing the real action).

See the below code:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
url = 'https://www.online.bmsupermercados.es/es/c/ofertas/99999?orderById=5&page=1'

try:
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 200)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Rechazar todo']"))).click()
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='use' and @*='#icon-cancel']")))
    for i in element:
        i.click()

    # handle pagination
    navigate_by_nums = True
    if navigate_by_nums:
        # navigate by numbers
        num = int(
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='paginator-input-box']/parent::div/following-sibling::span"))
            ).text.replace("de", "").strip()
        )
        for i in range(1, num + 1):
            p_input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "paginator-input-box")))
            actions.move_to_element(p_input) \
                .click(p_input) \
                .send_keys_to_element(p_input, Keys.CONTROL + "a") \
                .send_keys_to_element(p_input, Keys.DELETE) \
                .send_keys_to_element(p_input, str(i)) \
                .send_keys_to_element(p_input, Keys.ENTER) \
                .perform()
            wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID, "paginator-input-box"), str(i)))

            print(f"Moved to page: {i}")

            # do some parsing here
            # do some parsing here
            # do some parsing here

            time.sleep(1)
    else:
        # navigate by next button
        i = 1
        while True:
            next_btn = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                    (By.XPATH, "//cmp-tol-main-paginator//cmp-icon[@name='icon-right']/ancestor::a")
                )
            )
            if "u-disabled" in next_btn.get_attribute("class"):
                print(f"Finished at page: {i}")
                break
            else:
                actions.move_to_element(next_btn).click(next_btn).perform()

                i += 1
                print(f"Moved to page: {i}")
                wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID, "paginator-input-box"), str(i)))

                # do some parsing here
                # do some parsing here
                # do some parsing here

                time.sleep(1)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

There is a 'navigate_by_nums' flag you can change its value to test both approaches. Select the one which suits you best.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Not only you gave me three optional solutions, but more things to learn for future challenges. I'm really grateful.